# Odoo Server Error while running on mac ox sierra

Tags: python, odoo-10, passlib

I'm using mac os x Sierra
i have a problem while executing ./odoo-bin , then i already installed the passlib correctly .
I don't know why i have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace('odoo.addons')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2218, in declare_namespace
    declare_namespace(parent)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2234, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2201, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 246, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module(fullname, self.file, self.filename, self.etc)
  File "/Users/Mohamed_mac/odoo/odoo/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    import modules
  File "/Users/Mohamed_mac/odoo/odoo/modules/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
  File "/Users/Mohamed_mac/odoo/odoo/modules/graph.py", line 13, in <module>
    import odoo.osv as osv
  File "/Users/Mohamed_mac/odoo/odoo/osv/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import osv
  File "/Users/Mohamed_mac/odoo/odoo/osv/osv.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..exceptions import except_orm
  File "/Users/Mohamed_mac/odoo/odoo/exceptions.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tools.func import frame_codeinfo
  File "/Users/Mohamed_mac/odoo/odoo/tools/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from misc import *
  File "/Users/Mohamed_mac/odoo/odoo/tools/misc.py", line 16, in <module>
    import passlib.utils
ImportError: No module named passlib.utils
 i hope u to help me, thank you
```

Comment: do you run inside virtual env? please show pip freeze

Comment: I can t show u all package its too long but the passlib is already existed

$ pip2 freeze

Babel==2.3.4
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
decorator==4.0.10
docutils==0.12
ebaysdk==2.1.4
feedparser==5.2.1
passlib==1.6.5
pbr==3.1.1
Pillow==3.4.1
psutil==4.3.1
psycogreen==1.0
psycopg2==2.7.1
pydot==1.2.3
pyparsing==2.1.10
pyPdf==1.13
pyserial==3.1.1
Python-Chart==1.39
python-dateutil==2.5.3
python-ldap==2.4.27
python-openid==2.2.5
python-stdnum==1.6
pytz==2016.7
pyusb==1.0.0
PyYAML==3.12

Comment: I don't have a virtual env

Comment: A google search on *No module named passlib.utils* revealed [this question and answer](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/16451). It's a good idea to do some research before posting here.

Comment: i tried this solutions, but i still have the same problem

Comment: try reinstall odoo in new path